# How to generate a multi-domain (and/or wildcard) OpenSSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I tried Googling and haven't been able to find anything reliable that shows me how to generate the CSR. I have multiple domains, that I'd like added so I can't use the usual OpenSSL wizard:

```
*.domain1.com
*.domain2.com
```

How can I get this generated?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Which SSL certificate would I need for external AND internal domain names?](http://serverfault.com/q/672072/217116), [the answer](http://serverfault.com/a/672082/217116) exactly shows what you want.

Comment: You can now include multiple SAN requests inline with OpenSSL v1.1.1+ without the need for any prompts, `openssl.cnf` or `san.cnf` ... see this very helpful answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/198409/208757

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirements, you want to secure multiple domains and its unlimited numbers of sub-domains. You can do it with **multi domain wildcard certificate**.
To generate CSR using OpenSSL wizard, you have to follow below steps.

Login into your server.

Create an OpenSSL configuration file named san.cnf using the following information.

```
[ req ]
default_bits       = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = req_ext
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
stateOrProvinceName = State or Province Name (full name)
localityName        = Locality Name (eg, city)
organizationName    = Organization Name (eg, company)
commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = domain.com
DNS.2 = *.domain2.com
DNS.3 = *.domain3.com
DNS.4 = *.domain4.com
```

**Note:** Change or add additional DNS names as per your requirements.

Save the file and run the following OpenSSL command to create the Certificate Signing Request and a new Key file.

```
openssl req -out sslcert.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout private.key -config san.cnf
```

Now you have CSR file “domain.csr” and send it to your certification authority so they will issue a certificate with SAN.

Comment: This will depend on the reseller. Some will require the SAN to be contained within the CSR.

Comment: Also, an SSL cert for `*.example.org` will not be valid for `example.org`. You would need to specify both.

Comment: This answer pertains to CSR requests, not certification creation.